# How to change the frame size in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing on NetBeans, In my code, the picture stretches across the entire frame and is therefore slightly distorted, how to get the image size to set it's frame size?
I tried to assign the image size to the frame, but I did not succeed :(
how can i finished my programm?
P.s. excuse me for my bad English.
Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyJPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static int i = 0;

    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
    JButton button = new JButton("Next image"),
            button2 = new JButton("previous image");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(),
            panel2 = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJPanel gui = new MyJPanel();
        gui.go();
    }

    class Inner implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (i > 0) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    i = i - 3;
                } else {
                    --i;
                }
                button2.setText("previous image");
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(new Inner());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        File[] files = new File(Path).listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println(f.canRead() + " " + f.renameTo(f));
            images.add(new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath()).getImage());
        }
        if (i < images.size()) {
            g.drawImage(images.get(i), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);//here stretches the picture
        }
        System.out.print("hello world");
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (i < 3) {
            i = i + 3;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        button.setText("Next image");
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading in the same images repeatedly from within a painting method? Those methods need to be blazingly fast, and there's no need to re-read in images that have been read in before. Read them in once, say in the constructor, put them into variables, and in the painting methods, just *paint*, oh and call the super's method as well.

Comment: Myself, if I were swapping images, I'd create ImageIcons and swap the images in a JLabel.

Comment: That has no bearing. You read it in once, and not within a painting method.

Comment: I am new to Java and don't know the intricacies.I am managed to write this, would like to understand how to fix it.

Comment: Use a JLabel and ImageIcons, swap icons in your Timer. That's what I'd do.